# v-data-table Search in all columns

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a table with many rows and columns, I would like to add a search box that, when text is written, it will search the entire table and leave in the table only the rows that contain a match in one of the columns according to the entered text

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: You can find the solution even [in official docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#search)